# 'Undefined reference to ' error in GCC Eclipse

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I use Eclipse+GCC+MinGW.

**AbstractValue.h:**

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTVALUE_H_
#define ABSTRACTVALUE_H_

#include <string>


class AbstractValue {
public:
    virtual AbstractValue* add(AbstractValue*) = 0;
    virtual AbstractValue* sub (AbstractValue*) = 0;
    virtual AbstractValue* mul (AbstractValue*) = 0;
    virtual AbstractValue* div (AbstractValue*) = 0;
    virtual std::string toString () = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractValue() = 0;
};


#endif /* ABSTRACTVALUE_H_ */
```

**IntegerValue.h**

```
#ifndef INTEGERVALUE_H_
#define INTEGERVALUE_H_

#include "../AbstractValue/AbstractValue.h"
#include <string>

class IntegerValue: public AbstractValue {
private:
    int value;
public:
    IntegerValue(int);
    ~IntegerValue();
    int getValue();
    IntegerValue* add (AbstractValue*);
    IntegerValue* sub (AbstractValue*);
    IntegerValue* mul (AbstractValue*);
    IntegerValue* div (AbstractValue*);
    std::string toString();
};
```

**IntegerValue.cpp:**

```
#include "IntegerValue.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

IntegerValue::IntegerValue(int a) : value(a) {};

IntegerValue::~IntegerValue() {}


int IntegerValue::getValue() {
    return this -> value;
}

IntegerValue* IntegerValue::add (AbstractValue* another) {
    IntegerValue* anotherInteger = (IntegerValue*) another;
    int newValue = this -> getValue() + anotherInteger -> getValue();
    return new IntegerValue(newValue);
}

IntegerValue* IntegerValue::sub (AbstractValue* another) {
    IntegerValue* anotherInteger = (IntegerValue*) another;
    int newValue = this -> getValue() - anotherInteger -> getValue();
    return new IntegerValue(newValue);
}

IntegerValue* IntegerValue::mul (AbstractValue* another) {
    IntegerValue* anotherInteger = (IntegerValue*) another;
    int newValue = this -> getValue() * anotherInteger -> getValue();
    return new IntegerValue(newValue);
}

IntegerValue* IntegerValue::div (AbstractValue* another) {
    IntegerValue* anotherInteger = (IntegerValue*) another;
    int newValue = this -> getValue() / anotherInteger -> getValue();
    return new IntegerValue(newValue);
}

std::string IntegerValue::toString() {
    char *res = new char[1000];
    itoa(this -> value, res, 10);
    std::string a (res);
    delete[] res;
    return a;
}
```

I get `undefined reference to AbstractValue::~AbstractValue()` on `IntegerValue::~IntegerValue() {}`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
virtual ~AbstractValue() = 0;
```

Means pure virtual, with no implementation. This is wrong, destructors cannot be pure virtual with no implementation. Use this:

```
virtual ~AbstractValue() {}
```

i.e. an empty implementation.

(Side note: a destructor can be pure virtual WITH an implementation, but there is no reason to do this here)

Comment: You can easily google this. Also, a pure desturctor forces extending classes to write their own and allow for deleting a derived object through a pointer to a base class, so it's not at all useless.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I've never seen the that, at least not where the implementation is provided with the derived class, but I can imagine how it might be useful, to customise handling of a resource private to Base, depending on the derived class's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Pure `virtual` destructors must have an implementation (as opposed to pure `virtual` methods, which can be left un-implemented).

Answer (score 0):

Any derived class' destructor ( `~IntegerValue()`) must call the base class' destructor (`~AbstractValue()`), and so the destructor must still be defined (even if it's empty):

So,

```
// In file AbstractValue.cpp

AbstractValue::~AbstractValue(){ }
```